# Block any connection in the Microsoft Loopback Adapter with Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-firewall, loopback

What (inbound?) rule should one add in order to block any connection running inside the Microsoft Loopback Adapter?

Is that even possible? I heard that almost for the default loopback (127.0.0.1) any connection inside it just bypasses the Windows Firewall, since it's on the local computer.

I cannot remove the adapter.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by attempting to firewall loopback? (and no, you can not remove it since 1) It is not a physical adapter. 2) It is hardcoded in windows)

Comment: I want to disable connections via this adapter (I've asked for all of the connections as a first step since even this had not worked for me, I will next block specific ports). However, I'm talking about the Microsoft Loopback Adapter, a removable piece of software, but I believe it works pretty similar in this regard.